# WPF. Как программно вставить в Grid строку между другими строками

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Есть Grid, который определен вот так:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Content here...  -->
</Grid>
```

Пока все выглядит вот так:
[image: before]

Хочу, чтобы по кнопке добавлялась строка в таблицу после 3 строки (отсчет строк от 1), причем у этой строки свойство `Height="*"`. Должно все выглядеть примерно так:
[image: expected]

Хочу сделать что-то наподобие такого (естественно, пример не компилируется):

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Insert(2, new RowDefinition { Height = "*" });
```

Первый вопрос: как правильно программно свойству `Height` присвоить поведение `*`? Для auto есть отдельный `GridLength.Auto`, а вот для звездочки подобного не нашел.

И еще хотел спросить, нормальная ли это практика - добавлять/удалять строки в Grid программно? Как лучше реализовать подобное поведение?

У меня есть идея, которую я пока не реализовал: заранее добавить эту строчку в RowDefinition и каким-то образом ее скрывать (реализовать поведение Visibility.Collapsed для строчки, но я пока не придумал, как это сделать).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/hh673798

Comment: @АндрейNOP и какой тогда мне value передавать?

Comment: 1.0 например. `"*"` это то же самое что и `"1*"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP действительно, я почему-то думал, что нужно 0 ставить. Спасибо